# Can I add a Team (i.e. [Team Name]\Team) to the Project Collection Adminstrator group in DevOps?

Tags: security, permissions, azure-devops, admin, project

**Description**

I am adding project's team members as Project Collection Administrators within the Organisation. To make this easier, I wanted to add the Project Team group as such `[Team Name]\Team`. To enable more people to be added as admins as the project grows. This appears to be allowed^ but I get an error  "We are unable to add members to this group at this time. Please try again at a later time or contact support for help"

^ Link to DevOps Documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/manage-azure-active-directory-groups?view=azure-devops

**Other Tries**

I have tried doing it later and also added groups that belong to the organisation such as `[org name]\[Team lead Developers]` or `[org name]\Project Collection Test Service Accounts`. These are all allowed but not the group formed by Project Teams.

**Steps to the issues**

Add a project team group to one of the default organisation permissions groups such as the Project Collection Administrators.

**Error is:**

> We are unable to add members to this group at this time. Please try
>   again at a later time or contact support for help

I expect the group to be added like any other group.

Any ideas to this issue? 
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This is as designed.

The **Add** operations between groups need to be at the same level or a high level group added to the lower level group. For example an organization group can be added to a project group,the reverse is not possible .

So, if the group is a project group, then this project group could not be added to an organization group.

Comment: really appreciate for reaching out. To clarify, so in MSFT's example (linked above) demos adding [FabrikamProject]\Contributors, the group was created outside of devops within the Azure AD and then added?

Comment: @user11646850 Yes, it’s a AAD group which created in Azure Portal.

Comment: Hi, how are things going? Please let us know if there is any progress

Comment: I believe the OP is also having this issue when adding individual members (not just groups), as are we.

Would love to know if anyone ever figured this issue out. None of the posted solutions are applicable to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For Project level administration (not Organization level), you can make a specific Team have Project Administration level permissions from this menu:

`Project Settings > Security > (select team) > Permissions`

and then set the following to Allow:

`Edit project-level information`

Essentially, your goal will be to copy any desired permits from the `Project Administrators` to the [team] permits.

Really, you can set all these permissions to "Allow" if you really want that [team] to have "full" access to administer.

This will give that team a lot of flexibility to administer within the Project space.  It will not; however, let them administer licensing and other Org level items.  From my experience, you cannot add [Team] to [Org] level groups; though, you can add [Org] groups to [Project] and [Team] level groups.

[image]

If you really want large groups to administer, and you have AD integration; then you can add an AD email distro or security group to the `Project Collection Administrators` group.  That's not something I would ever do since that would be considered dangerous in my Company, but you may not have the same requirements for security, access, and cost controls.

Comment: Doesn't work.

Error persists, for all project administrators - both members of the Project Administrators group as well as Administrators added as individuals directly.

Comment: It is possible that your Organization administrator has set overriding Deny permissions.

Comment: I am the Org Admin. I only have "Allowed" and "Not Set" for organization-level permissions, and only project-level permission groups.

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is you CANNOT add a Team group to a Project Admin group and get inheritance.  The best you can do is just edit the Team permissions to get the desired effect.  I've added a picture (above) to clarify.

Comment: The only alternative to this is to build and apply enterprise Active Directory groups that get added to both Team and Project Admin groups; then you'd just be adding and removing people from those AD groups instead of doing it in Azure DevOps settings.  This may not be an option for many people.